# How to give with-statement-like functionality to class?

Tags: python, concurrency, with-statement

[I apologize for the inept title; I could not come up with anything better.  Suggestions for a better title are welcome.]

I want to implement an interface to [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) files that supports multiprocess-level concurrency through file-locking.  The intended environment for this module is a Linux cluster accessing a shared disk over NFS.  The goal is to enable the concurrent access (over NFS) to the same file by multiple parallel processes running on several different hosts.

I would like to be able to implement the locking functionality through a wrapper class for the `h5py.File` class.  (`h5py` already offers support for *thread*-level concurrency, but the underlying HDF5 library is not thread-safe.)

It would be great if I could do something *in the spirit* of this:

```
class LockedH5File(object):
    def __init__(self, path, ...):
        ...
        with h5py.File(path, 'r+') as h5handle:
            fcntl.flock(fcntl.LOCK_EX)
            yield h5handle
        # (method returns)
```

I realize that the above code is wrong, but I hope it conveys the main idea: namely, to have the expression `LockedH5File('/path/to/file')` deliver an open handle to the client code, which can then perform various arbitrary read/write operations on it.  When this handle goes out of scope, its destructor closes the handle, thereby releasing the lock.

The goal that motivates this arrangement is two-fold:

1. *decouple* the creation of the handle (by the library code) from the operations that are subsequently requested on the handle (by the client code), and
2. ensure that the handle is closed and the lock released, no matter what happens during the
   execution of the intervening code (e.g. exceptions, unhandled
   signals, Python internal errors).

How can I achieve this effect in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work, your class needs to implement the [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types).  Alternatively, write a generator function using the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator.

Your class might roughly look like this (the details of `h5py` usage are probably horribly wrong):

```
class LockedH5File(object):
    def __init__(self, path, ...):
        self.h5file = h5py.File(path, 'r+')
    def __enter__(self):
        fcntl.flock(fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        return self.h5file
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.h5file.close()
```

Answer (score 8):

objects that can be used in `with` statements are called context managers; and they implement a simple interface.  They must provide two methods, an `__enter__` method, which takes no arguments and may return anything (which will be assigned to the variable in the `as` portion), and an `__exit__` method, which takes three arguments (which will be filled in with the result of `sys.exc_info()`) and returns non-zero to indicate that an exception was handled.  Your example will probably look like:

```
class LockedH5File(object):
    def __init__(self, path, ...):
        self.path = path

    def __enter__(self):
        self.h5handle = h5handle = h5py.File(self.path, 'r+')
        fcntl.flock(fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        return h5handle

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_info, exc_tb):
        self.h5handle.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, a context manager and `with` statement. In general, destructors in Python are not guaranteed to run *at all*, so you should not rely on them as anything other than fail-safe cleanup. Provide `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, and use it like

```
with LockedFile(...) as fp:
    # ...
```